# Can't figure out right SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

## Short

Need to generate courses list and count

1. all
2. unanswered
3. answered but unchecked

Questions.

## Detailed

For getting this result I need to operate with 7 tables.

## UPDATE

Database structure

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9ExyO6ktYcOenZ1WlBwdlY2R3c

[image]

[For full-sized image click here](http://screencast.com/t/eY2MMc9L)

I will explain some of them:

1. `answer_chk_results` - checked answers table. So if some answer doesn't exist on this table, it means it's unchecked
2. `lesson_questions` - lesson <-> question associations (by id) table
3. `courses-lessons` - courses <-> lessons associations (by id) table

Only first problem seems not so difficult: To get all questions' count of course, my plan looks like below:

1. At first, we need to get all courses names list. Query will look like so:

   SELECT c.id, c.name FROM courses c
2. Then get all lessons from `courses-lessons` association table by every selected course from `1.` (Have no idea how to continue previous query)
3. Then, count **all questions** by selected lesson id (`lid` column) from `2.`

But I can't figure out how final SQL statement will look like for all 3 problem.

Any suggestions? Ask if something unclear for you.

Comment: instead of posting image provide table structure and data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Unanswered questions:** answered question is any question that has no answer in the answers table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM questions
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM answers)
```

**Answered but unchecked questions:**

```
SELECT *
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM answers
    WHERE id NOT IN answer_chk_results    -- unchecked answer
) a ON q.id = a.qid                       -- only answered questions
```

**Edit:** to get a list of courses with the unanswered, unchecked, all questions counts in one query:

```
SELECT c.id, c.name, COUNT(all.id) 'All', 
       COUNT(unanswered.id) 'Unanswered',
       COUNT(unchecked.id) 'Unchecked'
FROM courses c
INNER JOIN courses-lessons cl ON c.id = cl.cid
INNER JOIN questions all ON cl.id = all.lid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM questions
    WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM answers)
) unanswered ON cl.id = unchecked.lid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM questions q
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM answers
        WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT aid FROM answer_chk_results)
    ) a ON q.id = a.qid 
) unchecked ON cl.id = unchecked.lid
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

Comment: I know, sqls for them seperately but, read question carefully. The problem is.. I need to list courses and to place right to every course unanswered, unchecked, all questions count. Like that: http://screencast.com/t/eI9sWQvh instead of `test` will be course name, and instead of `0` will be all questions count. (There will be multiple field like `0` for unanswered, unchecked, all questions counts)

Comment: Please visit chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/592/mysql-and-relational-databases

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`answer_chk_results`
    ) a ON q.id = a.qid 
) unchecked ON cl.id = unchecked' at line 21

Comment: @epic_syntax, replace the `answer_chk_results` with `(SELECT aid FROM answer_chk_results)` as in my edit. Sorry

Comment: [Err] 1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: @epic_syntax, This error because you probably has two column names with the same name `id`. In this case you will need to alias them to differ from them. I can't see this in the query in my answer so try to ensure this as well in your query.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15963/discussion-between-epic-syntax-and-mahmoud-gamal)

Comment: I think it's related with query